# Database tuning and possibly unexpected results

Tags: java, database, performance, indexing

So I have a database that's working a bit slower than I would expect and I'd like to describe what I'm doing so hopefully I can verify I'm not missing some performance tweak.  Some details first:

- I'm using java and the database is H2 embedded (although I'm seeing similar results regardless of database).
- I've profiled / timed it and the problems are definitely in the database queries, specifically the executeQuery() call.
- For this example the database table has 60K rows but my query involves a subset of 25K rows yet takes a full 1/2 second to return.

Here's how I've set up the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE rows (
  id @AUTOTYPE@ PRIMARY KEY,

  x VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  y VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  z @TIMETYPE@ NOT NULL
)

CREATE INDEX rows_index ON rows(x, y, z);
```

(Note that the parameterization is for auto increment and timestamp, respectively)

And my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? ORDER BY z DESC
```

Now, I only care about the first row, but it needs to be the newest row, so in java it looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "foo");
stmt.setString(2, "bar");
stmt.setMaxRows(1);
```

Notice the last line has the setMaxRows() set to 1.  To reiterate, the entire 'rows' table has about 60K rows and the query would return 25K rows if I wasn't setting it to return only 1.

So am I doing everything I can?  Even though 1/2s (0.5s) is certainly not a long time it doesn't seem like 60K records should take that long, especially when it should be indexed.  And I know time is relative, so this is just a modern workstation, not running on some sort of load-balanced server.

Thoughts?  Thanks for taking a look.

EDIT: Updating with the things I've tried:

- I tried adding "LIMIT 1" to the end of the query, the way to limit the number of results in this database, and it didn't make a difference.  In fact, the database itself (H2) says to either use LIMIT or setMaxRows(), and in my results they perform the same.
- I tried indexing on the specific columns that I'm searching for, i.e., creating 3 index statements, but again it didn't make a performance difference.

Comment: This *may* be more appropriate for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks Jason, good point, I'm not familiar with all the stack options, I'll try there.  And @kdgregory, not sure what you mean, but my query only returns a single row although the entire result would include 25K rows if I weren't limiting it.

Comment: If a two-column predicate selects half the rows in the table, then indexing those two columns will not provide a benefit. The database will scan the index (which is at least as large as the table), then retrieve the selected rows from the table (or, if it's smart, from the index).

Comment: @kdgregory: Ok, that makes more sense now, I was trying to limit in a database neutral way.  I'll see if limiting it in the query makes a difference.

Comment: Before I actually answer this question, I have to ask: is this the *exact* query that you are trying to execute? Or is it some simplification that may or may not reflect the exact query. And have you looked at the query plan?

Comment: Actually, I have to run, so no time for a real answer. If this is the *exact* query, I'd suggest (1) dropping the index, and (2) reformulating the query as `select max(Z) where X = ? and Y = ?` (note that you already know X and Y, so no need to include them in the results, and therefore no need for a `group by`).

Comment: @kdgregory: It really is the exact query, the only difference is the table has many more columns than in my description.

Comment: @kdgregory: Sorry, my SQL isn't the greatest.  As I said, the table has many more columns, and I need all them where the max(z) row is selected.  I'm sure I can do this with some sort of group by, but I don't know how.  I'll try to figure it out, hopefully this makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that your index isn't very selective: the predicate on `X` and `Y` select roughly half the rows in the table. This means that your execution plan might look like the following:

1. Scan the index to find rows that satisfy the predicate on `X` and `Y`, returning a set of matching rowids.
2. For each rowid from step #1, retrieve the corresponding table row.
3. Sort those rows in descending order.
4. Return all rows to the client.
5. The database driver will discard all rows but the first, due to the `setMaxRows(1)`.

That's a fairly dumb plan, but it's the baseline. H2 might choose to sort the rowids returned by step 1, using the timestamps found in the index, but I wouldn't expect this. You can find the actual plan using the [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html#explain_plan) command provided by H2 (you should become intimately familiar with it).

We should, however, be able to do a bit better than that plan. If you know that you'll *always* want the most recent records, then it might suffice to change your index:

```
CREATE INDEX rows_index ON rows(x, y, z DESC);
```

This will return the set of rowids in step #1 in already-sorted order. The DB might still return all of those rows, but you won't be paying for the sort every time.

This might also open up the use of `top 1` in the select clause: the index scan (step #1) can stop as soon as the first match is made on `X` and `Y`.

If that doesn't work, then a correlated subquery might. I'm just typing this in, haven't run it, so it might contain typos or syntax errors, but it would look something like this (you should also be able to alias the two tables and directly relate the inner query to the outer, rather than duplicating the parameters):

```
select  *
from    ROWS
where   X = ?
and     Y = ?
and     Z =
        (
        select  max(Z)
        from    ROWS
        where   X = ?
        and     Y = ?
        )
```

As I said, `explain plan` is your friend. Try out a couple of queries and see what the database is doing, then try to nudge it into doing something different. When I read the H2 performance optimization guide, it seemed like it might be smart about query optimization.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback.  I'll try to digest it all tomorrow and let you know if I have any questions.  A quick note that using `LIMIT 1` didn't seem to help but I came up with a query identical to yours (the nested aggregate) and that indeed helped tremendously.  My query time went from about ~500ms to ~50ms, so an order of magnitude.  So thanks for the suggestion about using `max()`.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your

```
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? ORDER BY z DESC
```

requires to collect all such rows and sort them. A smart DB could see through and find out that it's equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? ORDER BY x, y, z DESC
```

and use the index for sorting. Is your DB that smart?

**UPDATE:** You could also try

```
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? AND z = (SELECT MAX(z) FROM rows  WHERE x = ? AND y = ?)
```

in case your DB is smart enough to handle the nested query efficiently. You should NOT do thing like fetching `MAX(z)` first and use it in a separate query, but you may want to try it for comparison.

---

You're fetching a single row, but does DB know it at the point it starts processing? I'd go for `TOP 1` or `LIMIT 1` or however it's called.

Comment: I thought when I created an index on 3 things it creates separate indexes for each?  If not, I should go read more about how indexing works.  And your "top 1" is a good idea, and the database may be able to optimize for that, but I was trying to do it in a database neutral way.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @rjcarr: No, it's a single index over all 3 columns. It's just like sorting people lexicographically (i.e., the usual way) by last and first names rather than creating two independent indexes. For a DB neutral way you can try some framework, but it doesn't pay for a tiny project. Trying to stay DB independent without it is futile.

Comment: I tried the LIMIT suggestion and it didn't make a difference.  It seems the driver is smart enough to look for the setMaxRows(), but this may not be true of all drivers.

Comment: @rjcarr: Or the DB is dumb enough to waste enough time elsewhere. Try `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see what the DB does. Given the very poor selectivity a full scan may be the best plan and then there's nothing to gain. There are also DB-specific commands to force or ignore an index, which you can try out.